# add second controller to pizero on Retropie

Tags: retropie, pi-zero

I've got a keyboard and a Snes usb controller connected to a pizero via a usb hub (not powered).
I can configure both of them with no problem. And each of them seem to keep the configuration. But when I load a game. It seems that both the keyboard and the Snes controller and controlling the same player one.

Is it possible to have 2 controllers working on a pizero?

Comment: and the reason for the downvote is....or are you too much of a troll?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have 2 controllers working on a pizero?

Yes. I've managed to do it with either usb SNES controller and a wiimote. And also with 2 wiimotes playing concurrently.
I bought [this bluetooth dongle](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/261155871712). And even with an unpowered usb hub it ran perfectly along with a wifi dongle and a SNES controller.

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/retropie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/Wiimotes-with-classic-controllers#getting-the-wiimotes-to-work) to pair the wiimotes.

I didn't manage to get a keyboard to work with a SNES controller. Or 2 SNES controllers side by side. Maybe it's just a matter of getting the right configuration at /home/pi/.emulationstation/es_input.cfg.